# Calling timers in C#

Tags: c#, timer

I was wondering if anyone could offer some advice. I need to automate a process within my program that when fingerprint has been captured, it automatically goes to the next page through calling ShowNext() in the wizard.

```
public partial class AddFingerprintsPage : Neurotec.Samples.WizardPage
...

        #region Scanner // Fingerprint Scanner
        public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Timer timer1 = new Timer();
            timer1.Interval = 1000; 
            timer1.start() // 

              {
                Form2 f2 = new Form2();
                f2.Show(); // Display Form2 which asks user to present finger..
              }
              if (capturing..)
                 { 
                  blah blah capture finger.. 
                  timer1.stop()
                  }

         }
```

....

```
public partial class WizardForm : Form
  ....
    public void ShowNext() // In the wizard form, go to the next page
    {
        ShowPage(_currentPage + 1, false);
    }
```

I am not sure what is the best away around this. I have tried making an if statement so when timer1.stop occurs in fingerprints then I call it in WizardForm and go to next page. But I am pretty sure I am not calling it correctly and even if I had I still have this error 'an object is required for the non-static field, method of property 'NeurotechSamples.AddFingerprintsPage.timer1'

```
    public void ShowNext()
    {
        if(Neurotec.Samples.Fingers.AddFingerprintsPage.timer1.stop()) // Not sure what to call here?
        ShowPage(_currentPage + 1, false);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why would you need a timer in the first place? If I understand it correctly, you just need to open the form and then react to the 'User has given his/her fingerprint' event. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do with the timer. As written, your timer code makes no sense at all.

Comment: Yes essentially I just need to open the form and when event then call next page. I wanted to start the process after a few seconds because instructions are displayed on a screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the AddFingerprintsPage, add a static bool and call it "Stopped" and set the value to true when the timer stops:

```
  public static bool Stopped = false;


  if (capturing..)
             { 
              blah blah capture finger.. 
              timer1.stop()
              Stopped = true;
              }
```

Then you can say:

```
 public void ShowNext()
{
    if(Neurotec.Samples.Fingers.AddFingerprintsPage.Stopped) 
    {
         ShowPage(_currentPage + 1, false);
    }
}
```

The error that you are getting is saying that you need to create a new instance of Neurotec.Samples.Fingers.AddFingerprintsPage in order to reference timer1 because it is not static.

Comment: Thanks for this.. do I need to if(Neurotec.Samples.Fingers.AddFingerprintsPage.Stopped = true) ?

Comment: You do not need to explicitly say == true in your if statement because it always checks for a condition to be true. Even a statement like if(Neurotec.Samples.Fingers.AddFingerprintsPage.Stopped == false) is saying check to see if that returns false, if it does, return true, if not return false.